# Which mobile app development framework should i use?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, css

I am a web developer. I know php html css and some js. So I was looking for a way to make native apps and found out that there are many framework i can use such as Sencha, phonegap, appmobi and Titanium. They seems all similer, i am have a hard to make decision which to use.
I work on windows OS and i dont have mac.

Comment: Titanium is very good but if you are using Windows so iPhone simulator wont be there.i think you cant do work on root level in Titanium

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This question is not programming related, StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested both PhoneGap and Titanium and I would go for Titanium. It seemed a lot easier to use to me but like every other frameworks, it showed its limits really quickly. 
However PhoneGap allows you to develop native plugins that are not hard to implements (good guys PhoneGap devs made a good doc)

Don't forget that frameworks like those 2 are just building web app into a native one (it's called a hybrid app) and they are extremely slow compare to real native apps.

Some would recommend you to use a MacOSX virtual machine but I'd recommend you to find a second-hand macbook or mac mini.

Also, remember to analyze what are your needs for your app and always think about the user experience. Slow app doesn't get much success.

Answer (score 0):

The most powerfull framework is Titanium, in my opinion. But PhoneGap is a good shot when using html/css/js.